# Is every set with this property uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a non-empty set $\Gamma = \{(\rho, \sigma)| (\rho, \sigma) \in (0,1)^ 2\}$. Set $\Gamma$ has the following property: For any $(\rho, \sigma) \in \Gamma$ and any $(w,v) \in \mathbb{N}^2$, there exists a $(\rho(w,v), \sigma(w,v)) \in \Gamma \backslash \{(\rho, \sigma)\}$ such that $\rho^w \sigma^v = \rho(w,v)^w \sigma(w,v)^v$. I conjectured that such $\Gamma$ must be an uncountable set but failed to prove it. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What was the motivation behind the conjecture - i.e., why do *you* think that $\Gamma$ is uncountable?

Comment: You seem to have define $\Gamma$ as $(0,1)^2$. Then you also claim that it has a certain property and so on. Instead you should write that your conjecture is "that every set $\Gamma\subseteq(0,1)^2$ with the property that ... must be uncountable".

Comment: Let us start with one element. In order to satisfy the property described above, countably many elements must be added to set $\Gamma$(I am able to show this rigorously). Consider each newly added element alone, again I need to add countably many elements. If I continue like this, the cardinality of set $\Gamma$ will be uncountable because the power set of a countable set is uncountable. However, I might add too much elements to set $\Gamma$ because one element with different power may equal to two other different elements with different power respectively. I feel this cannot happen to often.

Comment: I wrote about your last comment in an answer (because it seemed more appropriate, considering the length of what I had to say).

Answer (score 1):

No, your set can be countable. Just take the initial point $(1/2,1/2)$ and then for every natural $(w,v)$ choose a point $p(w,v)$ that satisfies the equation for the target value $(1/2,1/2)$. This is the first set of points that you add. Let $S_1$ denote this set. Then for every point $x \in S_1$, you follow a similar construction with $x$ being the target value to get a set of points $S_2(x)$ for each point $x$. Note $S_1$ is countable and $S_2 := \cup_{x \in S_1} S_2(x)$ is a countable union of countable sets and hence countable. So you can similarly construct a set $S_3(x)$ for every point $x \in S_2$, and indeed construct countable $S_k = \cup_{x \in S_{k-1}} S_k (x)$ for all natural numbers $k$. Then $\cup_k S_k$ is a countable union of countable sets, hence countable, and it satisfies your property. In general, any time you have a function $f: S \times X \to X$ where $S$ is countable, and you want to find a subset $X_1 \subset X$ such that $f(S \times X_1) = X_1$, you can find such $X_1$ that is countable.

Comment: Aww. I wast just going to write that! With $(\frac12,\frac12)$ as a starting point!

Comment: Lol I guess the canonical is universal.

Answer (score 1):

The suggest "proof" that you posted in the comment is flawed deeply.

You start with $\Gamma_0$ which contains just one element, say $(\frac12,\frac12)$. Then you define $\Gamma_{n+1}$ to be the set of all those which will witness the property *only* for pairs from $\Gamma_n$.

You agree that $\Gamma_1$ is countable, and if $\Gamma_n$ is countable, and in $\Gamma_{n+1}$ we add at most a countable number of elements for each point in $\Gamma_n$, then $\Gamma_{n+1}$ is also countable.

Now consider $\Gamma=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\Gamma_n$. This set is the countable union of countable sets, therefore it is countable. And given $(x,y)\in\Gamma$ and $(w,v)\in\Bbb N^2$ we have that for some $n$, $(x,y)\in\Gamma_n$ therefore the witnesses we seek are in $\Gamma_{n+1}$, and therefore already lie in $\Gamma$.

The fact that $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ is uncountable has nothing to do with this fact. You don't traverse all the sets of $\Bbb N$. You just start with one element, and you close down under the operations.

---

If we consider this as a model theoretic question, then you have a language with countably many function symbols. $\Gamma$, being a set closed under those functions, is simply a substructure. As the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem tells us, if the language is countable then there are countable substructures.